# How can I write scripts to test this dropdown functionality implemented in Ionic Angular using Selenium WebDriver with Java?

Tags: java, angular, selenium-webdriver, ionic-framework

How do I write Selenium WebDriver scripts in Java to interact with this Ionic Angular dropdown menu?

I want to click on the dropdown and select one element from the list.
The options in the dropdown are 'MANAGER' and 'TRAINEE'.

Angular code for the dropdown:

```
<ion-item mode="md" lines="none" class="fluent-textbox" *ngIf="grantedRoles.length > 1">
      <ion-select interface="popover" justify="start" (ionChange)="changeUserRole($event)" placeholder="Sign-in as"
                [selectedText]="userRole" name="userRole">
            <ion-select-option *ngFor="let grantedRole of grantedRoles; let i = index " style="color: var(--salt-theme-foreground)"
                [value]="grantedRole" [name]="grantRoles">{{grantedRole}} 
           </ion-select-option>
       </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Have you tried Explicit wait' ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class ExplicitWaitDropdownExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path/to/chromedriver");
       
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        try {
          
            driver.get("your-angular-app-url");

            WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.name("userRole"));
          
            dropdown.click();

            // Use explicit wait for the dropdown to be clickable
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
            WebElement option = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//ion-select-option[text()='MANAGER']")));

            // Click the desired option
            option.click();
 
        } finally {
        
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
}
```